# Eclipse project description file (.project) not showing in view "Navigator"

Tags: eclipse

Checking the file system from the windows explorer, I can confirm that file `.project` exists in my project. However in view `Navigator`, the file is not visible. I searched the internet for an answer without succeeding. The file `.project` isn't missing so this is another case. An answer was to verify if a file `.location` is located in `eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/project-name`, otherwise the workspace is corrupting. The latter was my case and I tried many suggestions to repair it but without succeeding (`.location` still missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `.project` can be filtered and thus hidden. Check `Filters` in view `Navigator` and ensure that `*.project` isn't checked (otherwise it will be hidden).
Concerning the file `.location`, based on this [source](http://www.rdeeson.com/weblog/99/relocating-eclipse-projects-the-project-description-file-project-for-xxx--is-missing.html), this file is designated to be used if you want to put `.project` outside the project folder (default), if it's puted in the default folder, `.location` won't exist.